# Column order of a composite clustered index in a ALTER TABLE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to add a composite primary key (2 columns) to an already existing table. This key will also be a clustered index, so the order of the columns is important.

I am using the following script:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] 
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Col1] ASC, [Col2] ASC)
```

I need `Col1` to be the first column of the clustered index, followed by `Col2`.

My question is if this script will do it (or do I need to explicitly set the order somehow?).

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That T-SQL statement is doing exactly what you say you need.

The order of the columns is the order in which you write them down in your T-SQL statement - there's no need nor any way to otherwise specify their order.

Your T-SQL statement will create a clustered index with `Col1` first, followed by `Col2` - just as you want it to be.